# Which protocol does Java's Socket use?

Tags: java, sockets, socketserver

I'm getting started with Java's `Socket` and `SocketServer` classes.

As mentioned above I would like to know which protocol (or however it is called) the Socket classes are using to communicate by default.

It is probably TCP, but I couldn't find anything specific, probably I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) use TCP/IP.

The [package overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html#package_description) for the `java.net` package is explicit about this, but it's easy to overlook.

UDP is handled by the [`DatagramSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) class.

Comment: Should add some doc links for the poor fellow.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [this oracle documentation post](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) sockets play with **TCP**. Many people mistakenly suppose that [Socket class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) handles UDP too, but UDP are handled by the [DatagramSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) class

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Java `Socket` use `TCP/IP`, read this when you're beginner

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html